# Вывод сообщения из ВК в консоль. VK api

Tags: vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

Кто знает, можно ли каким-нибудь образом с помощью VK api брать сообщения, которые тебе приходят?

Поясняю, тебе приходит сообщение в ЛС, и оно должно выводиться в консоль.

Если кто подскажет, буду благодарен.

Comment: В помощь документация vk api. Тебе нужна часть, которая про long polling. Во многих бибилотеках работа с ним реализована "из коробки". Учти: api сообщений уже несколько лет как закрыто, к нему имеют доступ только группы (что, очевидно, не твой случай) либо боты, по которым ты договорился с администрацией (это вряд ли получится). Есть способы обхода, однако они нарушают условия пользования ВК и о них поподробнее в сети.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Напишу Вам полноценное начало Бота

```
import vk_api 
import json
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor

while True:
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW: #Получение нового сообщения (event)
                 
                if event.to_me: #Если Вам
                    msg = event.text #Получение Сообщения
                    print(msg)

    

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)                 #Вывод ошибки в её случае
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не тянет на развернутый ответ. Напишите чуть подробнее, откуда брать event?

Comment: event нужно брать из модуля VkEventType. 
При импортировании данного модуля, event уже можно использовать